# MySql Connection in informatica

Tags: mysql, odbc, informatica

How do I set up a connection in informatica for  MySQL  to transfer data from oracle to Mysql.

regards,
Khairul Hasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below steps :

1. Go to SourceAnalyzer -> select sources --> Import from Database
2. A pop-up will open and click on the button.
3. Another pop- up will open and click on Add
4. Select DataDirect 6.1 MySQL Wire Protocol
5. Give the host name , schema name and test connect.

Comment: Hi Nitin, It is working for my local machine. But my informatica is running in Linux machine. So how can I configure it for my linux server. I mean the  MYSql ODBC configuration for Linux server.